# Variable inside a search pattern in python

Tags: python, search, variables, design-patterns

I have a soup from BeautifulSoup and I have a list of keys (key_image) which value or values I want to introduce in another list.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(stringapplet)
    key_image = ['archivo=', 'imagen=', 'image=', 'imaxe=', 'arquivo=']
    imageslist = []
```

This way I get the list of values for *archivo*:

```
    patron = re.compile(r"archivo='([\w\./]+)'")
    for tag in soup.findAll('param'):
        if patron.search(tag['value']):
            imageslist.append(patron.search(tag['value']).group(1))
```

good, but... I need in *imageslist* also searches of *"patrons"* like *archivo*: of *imagen*, of *imaxe*... etc. so I suppose I need to introduce a variable in a search pattern, then I do:

```
    for x in key_image:
        if string.find(stringapplet, x) != -1:
            expression = 'r' + '"' + x + "'" + '([\w\./]+)' + "'" + '"'
            patron = re.compile(expression)
            for tag in soup.findAll('param'):
                if patron.search(tag['value']):
                    imageslist.append(patron.search(tag['value']).group(1))
```

but *imageslist* is empty because the last line is never loaded.
¿?

I do *patron.pattern* and I get *r"archivo='([\w./]+)'"*   also, so what is wrong?

How can I do the search of all values of all key_images values?

Thanks.

Comment: You're confusing a string with a string *literal*.

Comment: give me more tips, please, I suppose I don't use http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-intro.php correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in key_image:
    if string.find(stringapplet, x) != -1:
        expression = r"%s'([\w\./]+)'" % x
        patron = re.compile(expression)
        for tag in soup.findAll('param'):
            result = patron.search(tag['value'])
            if result:
                imageslist.append(result.group(1))
```

Comment: It work!. now I must understand the reason. Thanks a lot, Frg. I'm sure I'll be a beginner for a long time!

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Didn't notice it was still there after splitting the original line (so that regexp search isn't run twice).